# How do make a model to for logging IPv4 and IPv6 ip addresses for quick lookup in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ipv6

I'm looking for a way to log IP addresses and user agents and then query against the list by IP. I was hoping to store the IP as efficiently as possible because the log could grow to be very large over time. What data type would I use for the IP address, string, long, or decimal? and how do I index the IP column for speed the Rails way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most efficient way is to use the [IPAddr](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/classes/IPAddr.html) class, and then store them in your database as integers